# How to insert appended dropdown into db

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

anyone, this is a long question so bear with me. So i have a dropdown in my form to select country. there is a button which will add another dropdown that allows users to select another country. So if user choose to add another dropdown, the values of the 2nd will not be inserted into the database, only the first value is inserted. below is my dropdown.

```
                <div class="editor-field" id="mb">  
                    Member Countries


                    <div id="jj">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Memberc, ViewBag.lCountry as SelectList, "--select--", new { @id = "tid0" })<br />
                    </div>
```

below is the button to add dropdown

```
                <div id="test">
                </div>
                <input type='button' value='Add' id='addButton'>
```

Then we have the javascript that does the work to clone dropdown.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#addButton").click(function () {
            var elements = $("select[id!='template']");
            var newElement = $("#jj").clone(true);
            var count = elements.length;
            if (count > 8) {
                alert('no more dropdowns');
            }
            else {
                newElement.attr('id', count);//rename new element so that it refers to     distinguished object instead of cloned object
                $("#test").append(newElement);
            }
        });

        $("#removeButton").live("click", function () {
            $(this).parents("div.jj:first").remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

heres the DAL that links the stored proc

```
    public static ListOfItems CreateSchemeCInsert(ListOfItems objListOfItems)
    {
        SqlDataReader rdrDataAccess = null;
        ListOfItems objListOfItemsDetails = null;
        SqlConnection database = new SqlConnection(MyCOODataConn.MyCOOConnectionString);

        //Insert Data in DB
        database.Open();
        SqlCommand databaseCmd = new SqlCommand("SP_APP_Specific_SchemeCInsert", database);//name SP in database
        databaseCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        databaseCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@User_scheme_master_id", objListOfItems.msi));
        databaseCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Country_id", objListOfItems.Memberc));


        rdrDataAccess = databaseCmd.ExecuteReader();
        objListOfItemsDetails = new ListOfItems();

        return objListOfItemsDetails;

    }
```

and my stored procedure looks pretty normal

```
    Insert into [dbo].[APP_Specific_Scheme_Country] 
(user_scheme_master_id, country_id)
Values (@schemeid,@Country_id)
```

so why is it only the first dropdown is inserted to the table? and not the 2nd, 3rd and so forth. feel free to ask anything if my explanation is not clear. sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that `objListOfItems` is only being populated with the one value, but since that isn't shown its just a well educated guess.